# problem book on linear algebra after Schaums 3000 problems in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

I have done *Schaum's 3000 solved problems in Linear Algebra* in following topics:
Now i am looking forward another problem book on linear algebra.

I have on my mind: *Linear algebra Problem Solver by REA editors* but unfortunately it is not available (I don't have visa card etc to buy it on amazon.com) in my country.

please suggest an alternative book

Comment: Is graduate level linear algebra what you want?

Comment: @Kugelblitz  yes graduate level.

Comment: "Not available in my country" is no longer a valid excuse these days (and hasn't been so for at least $10$ years now).

Comment: I've added some more books for wider variety of choice in the field of Matrix-Algebra as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some books which might be helpful.

1. [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0883853221/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853221)

This book is plain brilliant. I have come across it so many times while seeing my seniors worshiping endlessly for the skills and problems it imparts.

_

2. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Through-Practice-Collection-Solutions/dp/0521272890/

_

3. [http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Linear-Algebra-GraduateMathematics/dp/0387728287/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424761780&sr=1-1&keywords=linear+algebra+graduate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387728287)

Looks like one of the best books for graduates; reviews seems excellent.

_

4. [http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048663518X/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424761747&sr=1-6&keywords=linear+algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048663518X)

Cheap and reliable according to reviews.

Edit: For matrix algebra oriented books

1. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Econometric-Exercises-Abadir/dp/0521537460/

_

2. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Problems-solutions-introductory-advanced-calculus/dp/9812702024/

_

3. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrices-Linear-Algebra-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486660141/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1424763268&sr=1-5&keywords=matrix+algebra

_

4. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrices-Linear-Transformations-Edition-Mathematics/dp/0486663280/ref=pd_sim_b_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=10KS682EE2S443RRF0Y9

Answer (score 6):

Here is an extensive list, to the best of my knowledge:

- [Algebra Through Practice: Volume 2, Matrices and Vector Spaces](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Through-Practice-Collection-Solutions/dp/0521272866/), by Blyth and Robertson;
- [Algebra Through Practice: Volume 4, Linear Algebra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Through-Practice-Collection-Solutions/dp/0521272890/), by Blyth and Robertson;
- [Linear Algebra: Challenging Problems for Students](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebra-Problem-Dolciani-Mathematical-Expositions/dp/0883853221/), by Zhang;
- [Linear Algebra Problem Book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linear-Algebra-Challenging-Problems-Mathematical/dp/0801854598), by Halmos;
- [Problems and Theorems in Linear Algebra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Problems-Theorems-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/toc/0821802364), by Prasolov.

And a couple of books directed towards matrix theory:

- [Matrix Algebra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Econometric-Exercises-Abadir/dp/0521537460/), by Abadir and Magnus;
- [Problems and Solutions in Introductory and Advanced Matrix Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Problems-solutions-introductory-advanced-calculus/dp/9812702024/), by Steeb.