# Does there exist a problem book in Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Does there exist a problem book like Problems in Mathematical Analysis: Kaczor,Nowak in subjects like

- Abstract Algebra
- Linear Algebra
- Complex Analysis
- Number Theory

.

I want a book similar to the one stated as it has great problems and also solutions to all of them.

Please exclude Schaum Series

Comment: Probably a duplicate. Did you do a search first?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162879/221227. See link.   I think this should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very fine is

Berkeley Problems in Mathematics, by P.N. de Souza and J.N. Silva (Springer).